# Streamlit (Programming Design) - Generating widgets dynamically via for-loop

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, streamlit

**Background**

I have designed a form for generating fields using [streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/), where each row is:

1. Field Label - `text`
2. Field Name - `text_input`
3. Option - `selectbox`

**Design**

1. A slider widget is used to assign a numerical value into a [session_state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state) variable
2. That numerical variable is used by a for loop to loop and generate fields as below:
   [image]
3. If a specific option is selected, i.e. 'Option B' a radio button widget is triggered.
4. If the radio button had value of 'Yes', the former below is displayed, doing the following:

- An on-call function `gen_custom_field()` is triggered incrementing the slider by 1 if radio is 'yes', or decrementing back if it radio is 'No'
- Call the function `generate_field()` to draw an ad-hoc custom field.
- Since the slider variable is updated, the for loop reads it and draws extra field.

[image]

**Problem**

> - Since the slider variable is updated, the for loop reads it and
>   draws extra field. I would really appreciate guidance around having a proper design as I've been struggling.

How to generate extra field, having Field 1, Field 2, Field 2_sys and Field 3 without Field 4 with the slider value set to 4?

```py
import streamlit as st

# Initialize session state
if 'fields_count' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.fields = 1
if 'radio' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.radio = 'No'
if 'switch' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.switch = False

def gen_cusom_field():
    if st.session_state.radio == 'Yes':
        st.session_state['c1_fields'] += 1
    elif st.session_state.radio == 'No' and st.session_state.switch == True:
        st.session_state['c1_fields'] -= 1
    else:
        pass
    return


def generate_field(key, field:str=None, option:str='', value:str=None):
    c1, c2, c3, c4 = st.columns([0.5, 1, 2,1], gap="small")
    with c1:                                # Field title (i.e. Field 1)
        c1.markdown("#")
        st.write(f'Field {key}')
    with c2:                                # Field text input
        field_input = st.text_input(label=f'Enter field {key} name',
                                    value = '', 
                                    key = f'row_{key}_c2' 
                                    )
    with c3:
        lookup_dict = {'':'','Option A':'some_func', 'Option B':'some_func', 'Option C':'some_func'}
        list_options = list(lookup_dict.keys()) # A list of functions options
        choice = st.selectbox(label='Choose data type', 
                              options = list_options, 
                              key = f'row_{key}_c3' 
                              )
        st.session_state["choice"] = choice
    with c4:
        if choice == 'Option B':
             radio = st.radio('Add associate columns?',['Yes','No'], index=1, on_change = gen_cusom_field, key = 'radio')
    return field_input, choice



with st.form('init_rows_form'):                                                                              # Init form - with user input rows
    st.session_state["fields_count"] =  st.slider(label='**Select number of fields**', min_value=1, max_value=5, key='c1_fields')

    if st.form_submit_button("Select"):                                                                       
        st.session_state['step'] = 1

for i in range(1,st.session_state["fields_count"]+1):                                                 # A foundational loop that re-draws row (generate_field () UI Component)                                                            
    inputs = generate_field('{}'.format(i))
    if inputs[1] == 'Option B' and st.session_state["radio"] == 'Yes':
        generate_field('{}_sys'.format(i), field='Gender')
        st.session_state.switch = True
        #break
    elif st.session_state["radio"] == 'No':
            st.session_state.switch = False
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this design with the below workaround, where:

1. Flag if `Option B` is selected and radio button is equal to 'yes'.
2. Set a toggle switch variable to True. ( to know the user selected radio yes at least once)
3. Call my ad-hoc/custom function in a different loop after the main one if the flag from step 1 is True to add the extra row field.
4. use a call-back function to update slider value (using key) to increment.
5. use a call-back function to update slider value, decrement slider value if the user selected yes at least once (from step 2).

**Please** let me know if there are better design to this problem.

```py
import streamlit as st
import re

# Initialize session state
if 'fields_count' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.fields = 1
if 'radio' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.radio = 'No'
if 'switch' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.switch = False

def gen_cusom_field():
    if st.session_state.radio == 'Yes':
        st.session_state['c1_fields'] += 1
    elif st.session_state.radio == 'No' and st.session_state.switch == True:
        st.session_state['c1_fields'] -= 1
    else:
        pass
    return 

lookup_dict = {'':'','Option A':'some_func', 'Option B':'some_func', 'Option C':'some_func'}
list_options = list(lookup_dict.keys()) # A list of functions options
def generate_field(key, field:str=None, option:str='', value:str=None):
    c1, c2, c3, c4 = st.columns([0.5, 1, 2,1], gap="small")
    with c1:                                # Field title (i.e. Field 1)
        c1.markdown("#")
        st.write(f'Field {key}')
    with c2:                                # Field text input
        field_input = st.text_input(label=f'Enter field {key} name',
                                    value = '', 
                                    key = f'row_{key}_c2' 
                                    )
    with c3:
        list_options = list(lookup_dict.keys()) # A list of functions options
        choice = st.selectbox(label='Choose data type', 
                              options = list_options, 
                              key = f'row_{key}_c3' 
                              )
        st.session_state["choice"] = choice
    with c4:
        value_input = None
        if choice == 'Option B':
             value_input = st.radio('Add associate columns?',['Yes','No'], index=1, on_change = gen_cusom_field, key = 'radio')
    return field_input, choice, value_input



with st.form('init_rows_form'):                                                                              # Init form - with user input rows
    st.session_state["fields_count"] =  st.slider(label='**Select number of fields**', min_value=1, max_value=5, key='c1_fields')

    if st.form_submit_button("Select"):                                                                       
        st.session_state['step'] = 1
        
elements = []
pattern = re.compile(r'r\d+_c\d+')
radio_value = None
print('Run: ===============')
count = st.session_state["fields_count"]+1
if  st.session_state["radio"] == 'Yes':
     count = st.session_state["fields_count"]+1 - 1
for i in range(1,count):                                                 # A foundational loop that re-draws row (generate_field () UI Component)                                                            
            inputs = generate_field('{}'.format(i))
            element = {f'r{i}_c2'.format(i):inputs[0],                                                        # Key: r1_c2 - value: text input -> df field name
                    f'r{i}_c3':inputs[1],                                                                 # Key: r1_c3 - value: List choice -> dummy function
                    f'r{i}_c4':inputs[2]
                    }
            elements.append(element)
            print(element)
for d in elements:
        for d in elements:
            if list(d.values())[1] == 'Option B' and list(d.values())[2] == 'Yes':
                radio_value = True
                st.session_state.switch = True
            #break
if radio_value == True:
    inputs = generate_field(key = '{}.1'.format(i))
elif st.session_state["radio"] == 'No' and st.session_state.switch == True:
    st.session_state.switch = False
```

1- Select 3 fields (Initial)

[image]

2- Select 'Option B' and 'Yes' (Increment)
[image]

3- Select 'No' for option B (Decrement)
[image]